# Are the projections defined on a cartesian product surjective functions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Following a reference from "General Topology" by Stephen Willard

[image]

Well I ask to me if the projection maps are a surjective functions.

To prove this I thought to use the Choice Axiom. So as in the definition let be $\mathfrak{X}=\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ an indicizated collecion of not empty sets: by the Choice Axiom we can organize the elements of any $X_\alpha$ in a transfinite succesion, that is $X_\alpha\equiv\{x_\gamma\}_{\gamma\in|X_\alpha|}$; then let be $\overline{\alpha}\in A$ and for any $\alpha\neq\overline{\alpha}$ let be $x_{\alpha_0}$ the first element of $X_\alpha$, through every elements of $X_\overline{\alpha}\equiv\{x_\gamma\}_{\gamma\in|X_\overline{\alpha}|}$ we can make a collection of functions
$$
\Xi=\Biggl\{\xi_\gamma\in \Biggl(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha\Biggl)^A: \xi_\gamma(\alpha)=\begin{cases}x_{\alpha_{0}},\quad 
if\quad\alpha\neq\overline{\alpha}\\x_\gamma,\quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases}  \Biggl\}_{\gamma\in|X_\overline{\alpha}|}
$$
and so we observe that $\xi_\gamma\in\Pi_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$ and that $\pi_\overline{\alpha}(\xi_\gamma)=x_\gamma$ and from this it is clear that the projection $\pi_\overline{\alpha}$ on $X_\overline{\alpha}$ is surjective.

Is my proof correct? if not how prove the assertion? Pheraps is the assertion false?

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: The assertion is true for any family of **nonempty** sets.

Comment: Okay, then what can you say about my proof?

Comment: Yes, it is correct (if the sets are nonempty as commented above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is okay, and as mentioned in the comments, you need to throw in the assumption that the sets are not empty.

Nevertheless, the proof can be improved. The axiom of choice is more diverse than just well-orderings. There is a better proof here.

By the axiom of choice $\prod X_\alpha$ is non-empty, so we can fix some $f$ in the product. Now for every $\alpha$, and for every $x\in X_\alpha$, we can define $f_{\alpha,x}$ as modifying $f$ on the $\alpha$th coordinate, as you did.

Comment: This is a better proof since it is in fact a proof in ZF that a non-empty product admits projections. Even if the sets whose product we took cannot be well-ordered.

Comment: Anyway I ask to me if the assertion is equivalent to the Choice Axiom: surely I know that the Choice Axiom is equivalent to claim that for any collection of not empty set the its cartesian product is not empty; but using this euquivalece (or else in other  any way) could I argue that if the  the projection maps are surjective then the Choice Axiom holds?

Comment: Yes, because any counterexample would mean a collection of nonempty sets with an empty product.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understead: could you explain better? Anyway I'm posting an another query about this question.

Comment: So if the projection maps are surjective and if we supposed that the Choice Axiom is false then surely there exists a not empty collection of not empty set such that its cartesian product is empty, but if this was true then the correspodent projections were not surjective and this is a contradiction in relation to the original assumption: perahps is it this what you want say?

Comment: There is no surjection from the empty set onto a non-empty set. If the axiom of choice is false, there is a product of non-empty sets which is itself empty. So there are no projection.

Comment: Okay, now it's clear, thanks!